# select query respecting conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have my table containing 4 Columns (id, val1, val2, val3).
Does anyone knows how to select rows where val3 is the same where val1 is different.

for example

```
row1: (id1, user1, matheos, cvn)
row2: (id2, user2, matheos, cvn)
row3: (id3, user3, Claudia, bnps)
```

then i return the row1 and row2.

Comment: "where val3 is the same for 2 val1" . . . What does that mean?

Comment: I suggest posting what you have tried so far.

Comment: @GordonLinoff like in my example in row 1 and row 2 val3 value is the same and value val1 is different.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is not entirely clear, but the following query will find matching rows according to the criteria you specified:

```
select a.*, b.*
from my_table a
join my_table b on b.val3 = a.val3 
               and b.val2 <> a.val2 
               and b.id < a.id
```

In order to produce the rows separately, you can also do:

```
select *
from my_table a
where exists (
  select null from my_table b where b.val3 = a.val3 and b.val2 <> a.val2
)
```

Comment: `a` and `b` as "aliases" for the same table. You need to use aliases when using the same table multiple time, in order to avoid confusion on the column names.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation, you can try this:

```
select distinct t1.* from mytable t1 
JOIN mytable t2 where t1.val3 = t2.val3 
and t1.val1 != t2.val1;
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9535ecb/1)

Comment: Try the sql fiddle link. And share what error are you getting. Based on what you explained, this works.